# MacOs Intellij CE giving access permission to Finder

Tags: macos, permissions, finder, intellij-idea

The first time I tried to remove a project from Intellij CE on MacOs, I got a prompt to allow access/permission to Finder.  I denied it.  So now Intellij removes the project from it's knowledge, but Finder still shows it.  In hind sight I should've given permission so that removal of projects would be reflected in Finder as well.  I've removed the app as well as any Library/... files and reinstalled, but the prompt for access never shows.

Any idea on how to get this reset?

Answer (score 0):

So, not sure where the issue you are having with Intellij is the same as mine. But I was developing an application which also had to request finder access. Which I denied and then the permission request was not shown. 
I found the possibility to set access in System Preferences -> Privacy -> Automation.

Hope that helps.